# How to integrate a python bolt to a java topology for Apache Storm?

Tags: java, python, serialization, apache-storm, stormcrawler

I was trying to integrate a simple python bolt to an already configured storm topology created using Apache Storm and Storm Crawler SDK. 
I was following the instructions provided [here](https://medium.com/@Sugeesh/connecting-python-bolt-for-apache-storm-topology-af6c2e3f2200)

But I am constantly getting error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Shell Process Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\<PATH>\storm.py", line 217, in run
    tup = readTuple()
  File "D:\<PATH>\storm.py", line 74, in readTuple
    cmd = readCommand()
  File "D:\<PATH>\storm.py", line 67, in readCommand
    msg = readMsg()
  File "D:\<PATH>\storm.py", line 42, in readMsg
    return json_decode(msg[0:-1])
  File "D:\<PATH>\storm.py", line 30, in <lambda>
    json_decode = lambda x: json.loads(x)
  File "C:\Users\akumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\akumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\akumar\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt.handleError(ShellBolt.java:227) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt.access$1100(ShellBolt.java:72) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt$BoltReaderRunnable.run(ShellBolt.java:348) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
96398 [Thread-40] ERROR o.a.s.t.ShellBolt - Halting process: ShellBolt died. Command: [python, D:/<PATH>/ClassifyBolt.py], ProcessInfo pid:12708, name:classify exitCode:0, errorString: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
Serializer Exception:


    at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellProcess.readShellMsg(ShellProcess.java:127) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt$BoltReaderRunnable.run(ShellBolt.java:330) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
96399 [Thread-40] ERROR o.a.s.d.executor - 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
Serializer Exception:


    at org.apache.storm.utils.ShellProcess.readShellMsg(ShellProcess.java:127) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.task.ShellBolt$BoltReaderRunnable.run(ShellBolt.java:330) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
```

I was trying to add the created bolt within the sample crawler example provider by the storm-crawler website. In my view, it seems to look like python bolt is not getting the stream from its previous component in the topology.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to your bolt's python process printing out some log output to stdout. By default, multilang Storm bolts use the process' stdin/stdout for communication with the Java process.

Using [pystorm](https://github.com/pystorm/pystorm) as your Python bolt infrastructure would allow you to use different streams for this communication, such as UNIX named pipes or sockets, and free up stdout for the usual logging.

Comment: Unlikely. The python process can't read the Tuple, not the ShellBolt impl can't read the python output.

Comment: @ndtreviv can you explain your comment?